# Dynamically adding HTML via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Good Day,

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that I'm working on and have a partial view with one row of data.

```
<div class="row paymentRow">
    <div class="col-xs-4">Additional Invoices</div>
    <div class="col-xs-8"><input type="text" style="width: 100%"/></div>
</div>
```

I have a button that when clicked, it adds additional rows to the DOM after the  after the last div with the class "row paymentRow".

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <button type="button" id="Add">Add Row</button>
    <button type="button" id="Ok">Ok</button>
    <button type="button" id="Cancel">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

The jQuery to add the additional row works:

```
$(function() {
    $("#Add").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var row = '<div class="row paymentRow">' +
            '<div class="col-xs-4">&nbsp;</div>' +
            '<div class="col-xs-8"><input type="text" style="width: 100%"/></div>' +
            '</div>';

        $("div.modalUploadWidth div.row:last").after(row);
    });
});
```

My question is:

Is there a cleaner way to represent the HTML that is being dynamically constructed and assigned to row?  I'm not a big fan of magic strings like this.  Not only that, but there will be multiple instances of where I need to inject javascript into the DOM.

I know that I can put the string into a Resource and access it from there.  I also know that Handlebars can do this by storing the javascript template into an external file and binding the contents of the external file to the DOM.

I'm trying to find alternatives I may be overlooking.

TIA,

coson

Comment: One good approach is to use Client side binding libraries like `Knockout JS`, where you can manipulate arrays and make them dynamically bind to UI. If you need, I can give you a quick sample.

Comment: @ramiramil,  could you give me an example?

Comment: I think this title is a little misleading as it really doesn't have to do with C# other than the fact your project is MVC - but this could relate to anyone using any type of web framework, and would probably yield you more results to adjust the tags and title as such.

Comment: If you will already have your first row instantiated on the page when you click the button, you can just clone that row instead of building one up from a string. Let me know if you need to see it in action.

Comment: You could use something like handlebars as a template and use `.append()` to add it.

Comment: @Todd, that's ok.  Another poster posted the solution that you're suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//take existing row (you've said there is always at least one row)
$(".paymentRow").
//take last (maybe there s already more than one)
last().
// create deep copy
clone().
//append it as last element to the parent element
appendTo(".modalUploadWidth");
```

Comment: that is cool.  This does solve the immediate problem of not including html in the javascript for *this* particular scenario.  But I have multiple scenarios in my website that will have different html be inserted into the dom.

Comment: If you're going to have a lot of these instances then it might be worth your while to check out a templating solution such as Handlebars.

Comment: You could load static html file (have templates folder) with jQuey. $("<div class="row paymentRow">").appendTo(".modalUploadWidth").load(url_to_the_page);

Answer (score 2):

Client side binding library like `KnockOut JS` would be more appropriate to make dynamic controls on client side. Here goes a simple `Knockout JS` Sample - **https://dotnetfiddle.net/fmwTtJ**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>  
        <!-- JS includes -->
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>       
        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
    </head>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: persons">
        <tr>
            <td><input data-bind="value: LastName"/></td>
            <td><input data-bind="value: FirstName"/></td>
        </tr>        
    </tbody>
</table>
<button data-bind="click: $root.addPerson ">Click</button>
<script>
    var ViewModel = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.persons = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.addPerson = function(){
            self.persons.push(new Person('Last Name','First Name'));
        };
    }

    var Person = function(lastName, firstName) {
        var self = this;
        self.LastName = ko.observable(lastName);
        self.FirstName = ko.observable(firstName);   
    }; 

    vm = new ViewModel()
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
</script>
</html>
```

When you click on the button, it will add a new row -

[image]

Comment: this is really helpful.  Not only that, but didn't know about .NET fiddle for ASP.NET MVC.  Kudos for this.  I don't think that SO allows me to split bounties for you and bjaksic.  But I would like to create another similar question and award you the bounty.  Unless you know of something I'm missing.

Comment: I don't think there is a need for you to create another question. If you have similar questions but other than the what you just solved, then post them and let me know. I will try my best to solve them.